# Use decorator to apply memoization when produce Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, decorator

Leetcode introduced a memoization recursion template to calculate Fibonacci number

> For the sake of comparison, we provide the implementation of Fibonacci number solution with memoization below.
>
> As an exercise, you could try to make memoization more general and non-intrusive, *i.e.* applying memoization without changing the original function. (*Hint*: one can refer to a design pattern called **decorator**).

```py
def fib(self, N):
    """
    :type N: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    cache = {}
    def recur_fib(N):
        if N in cache:
            return cache[N]

        if N < 2:
            result = N
        else:
            result = recur_fib(N-1) + recur_fib(N-2)

        # put result in cache for later reference.
        cache[N] = result
        return result

    return recur_fib(N)
```

Employed the template to solve [509.Fibonacci Number - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/fibonacci-number/)

> 509. Fibonacci Number2
>
> The **Fibonacci numbers**, commonly denoted `F(n)` form a sequence, called the **Fibonacci sequence**, such that each number is the sum of the two preceding ones, starting from `0`and `1`. That is,
>
> ```
> F(0) = 0,   F(1) = 1
> F(N) = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2), for N > 1.
> ```
>
> Given `N`, calculate `F(N)`.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2
> Output: 1
> Explanation: F(2) = F(1) + F(0) = 1 + 0 = 1.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: 3
> Output: 2
> Explanation: F(3) = F(2) + F(1) = 1 + 1 = 2.
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: 4
> Output: 3
> Explanation: F(4) = F(3) + F(2) = 2 + 1 = 3.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 0 ≤ `N` ≤ 30.

The memoization solution

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}
    def fib(self, N: int) -> int:
        #memoization solution 
        if N < 0 or N == None: return None
        if N in self.cache: return self.cache[N]
        if N < 2: 
            self.cache[N] = N
            return N 
        else:
            res = self.fib(N-1) + self.fib(N-2)
            self.cache[N] = res 
            return res
```

Get a relative good score:

> Runtime: 36 ms, faster than 80.05% of Python3 online submissions forFibonacci Number.
>
> Memory Usage: 13.1 MB, less than 5.02% of Python3 online submissions for Fibonacci Number.

The tutorial metioned that

> As an exercise, you could try to make memoization more general and non-intrusive, *i.e.* applying memoization without changing the original function. (*Hint*: one can refer to a design pattern called **decorator**).

Following the guidline to write a `cache`decorator.

```py
@recur_cache
def fib(N):
    #basic solution
    if N < 0 or N == None : return None
    if N < 2: return N
    else:
        return fib(N-1) + fib(N-2)

cache = {}
def recur_cache(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        if arg not in cache:
            cache[arg] = func(arg)
        return cache[arg]
    return wrapper
```

Unfortunately, it's very hard to place `cache` inside the decorator.

If cache was renamed `memo`,lots of manual jobs should be done, and the solution is not competitvie than the non-decorator none.

How could solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _it's very hard to place cache inside the decorator._?

Comment: Putting `cache = {}` inside `recur_cache` works for me, if one moves the definition of  `fib` below the definition of `recur_cache`.

Comment: could you please transmit the  comment to answer. @L3viathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `fib` is defined after `recur_cache`, and put the definition of `cache` inside `recur_cache`:

```
def recur_cache(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(arg):
        if arg not in cache:
            cache[arg] = func(arg)
        return cache[arg]
    return wrapper


@recur_cache
def fib(N):
    #basic solution
    if N < 0 or N == None : return None
    if N < 2: return N
    else:
        return fib(N-1) + fib(N-2)
```

---

To make this applicable to functions of any signature (not just those with a single positional argument), we can capture the *args and **kwargs of the call and store those as keys in the cache:

```
def recur_cache(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = (args, frozenset(kwargs.items()))  # dicts aren't hashable
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return wrapper
```